# Is it possible to apply Context-aware access when using managed Google accounts as a way to sign in to third-party cloud apps?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-identity

Here are an example. Let's imagine we use a cloud app, for example, [Intercom](https://www.intercom.com/) and we [forced Intercom users to use their G Suite accounts](https://www.intercom.com/help/en/articles/181-protect-your-account-with-2fa-and-google-sign-on) to sign in to Intercom.

We know that Google provides an ability to set up [Context-aware access](https://cloud.google.com/iam) with G Suite Enterprise or Cloud Identity Premium licenses.

So here is the question: if we have G Suite Enterprise or Cloud Identity Premium licenses can we apply Context-aware access rules (for example, restrictions by IP) on the process of signing in to third-party cloud apps (like Intercom) using G Suite managed accounts?

This is not traditional [Single sign-on (SSO)](https://cloud.google.com/identity/sso), this is [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web).

Comment: No. This page lists the apps that can have Context Aware Access support: https://support.google.com/a/answer/9275380?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, I haven’t go the “reputation” yet to make a simple comment , so here is what I have found so far :

According to the documentation, one of context-aware-access features is :
“Enforce context-aware access policies for web apps hosted on GCP, on your premises, or other public clouds, including Amazon Web Services (AWS) and Microsoft Azure.” [1]

Therefore what you are asking should be possible.

[1] Features
https://cloud.google.com/context-aware-access

Comment: It seems that this is only possible for your own apps, not for third-party apps 